# How do I use rows from one data frame to select identical rows in another data frame and use these for additional filtering of "paired" rows?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame `df1` that contains the rows of another data frame `df2` (I only have one row in this question for a simpler visualisation of the problem). The data in `df1` is organised in pairs according to `Cat`. What I need to do is use the rows from `df2` to make a data frame with both rows of each pair. That is, the end goal is to have a data frame with only the pairs from `df1` as shown in `dfgoal`.

```
df1 <- data.frame(Source = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"),
Order = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
Name = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A" ),
Cat = c("A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A3", "A3"),
Vol = c("35", "43", "none", "none", "63", "24"))

df2 <- data.frame(Source = c("1"),
Order = c("4"),
Name = c("A" ),
Cat = c("A2"),
Vol = c("none"))

dfgoal <- data.frame(Source = c("1", "1"),
Order = c("3", "4"),
Name = c("A", "A"),
Cat = c("A2", "A2"),
Vol = c("none", "none"))
```

My original data frames are much larger with more variables so I was hoping that there was a way to use the rows from `df2` for filtering purposes in `df1` so I don't need to specify column values that I can see from `df2`. I tried using the group_by function from the dplyr package in the hopes that the paired row (`Order == "3"` in this example) would stay grouped when joining the identical rows from `df1` and `df2`. Needless to say it didn't work. I ended up with only the row from `df2`.

```r
df_attempt <- df1 %>% group_by(Source, Name, Cat) #dplyr package

df_attempt <- inner_join(df_attempt, df2) #dplyr package
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure why the print function isn't working.

Comment: We don't need the `print(.)` calls or their output.

Comment: using `inner_join` ignores `group_by`, that kind of operation does not have meaning; "groups" should be covered in the `by=` clause of `inner_join` (that you are ignoring). My guess is starting with `inner_join(df2, df1, by = c("Source", "Name", "Cat"))`, though (1) I'm inferring the need to join by source, name, and cat, and (2) there is a little clean up (or pre-conditioning) required to deal with the `Order.x`/`Order.y` (and `Vol.*`) columns.